# How can I bypass the execution of a method in a RhinoMocks mock?

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, rhino-mocks

I use RhinoMocks for a very simple test (I have to say I'm a beginner here). I tried to mock my object like this

```
var mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<MyClass>();
```

create a helper stub :

```
var stubLinkedObject = MockRepository.GenerateStub<MyClass>();
```

then execute some logic which should call the method `AddLink` of the class `MyClass` with my stub argument. At the end of the test I simply assert that this method was actually called with

```
mockAction.AssertWasCalled(a => a.AddLink(stubLinkedObject));
```

I injected the correct dependency and the method is actually called. However, the problem is that the **real** implementation in `MyClass` is called and results in crash because some logic just can't be executed (link collection is not available etc.). How can I bypass the execution and simply check whether a method is called ? I have tried something like

```
mockAction.Stub(a => a.AddLink(null)).IgnoreArguments().Do(null);
```

before I go into the execution but this doesn't seem to work(I only get some exceptions). Any ideas and probably an explanation why the mock is executing the method logic at all ?

Comment: Is your method AddLink virtual?

Comment: No it's not, probably that's the problem :)

Comment: I'm confused. Normally there should be one object instance of the class under test which is not mocked/stubbed. You only seem to have mocks and stubs. Mocking and stubbing is only for the collaborator objects that you need to take control of during the test.

Comment: Actually the part (and the class) which is under test is missing, and the test here is that this object as a part of its execution calls the AddLink method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce. Here is the code which works fine for me

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var classMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<MyClass>();
    var linkedMock = MockRepository.GenerateStub<MyClass>();

    classMock.Expect(c => c.MyMethod(linkedMock));

    classMock.MyMethod(linkedMock);

    classMock.AssertWasCalled(c => c.MyMethod(linkedMock));
}

public class MyClass
{
    public virtual void MyMethod(MyClass linkedClass)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyMethod is called");
    }
}
```

Comment: Like the question, this answer confuses me. You're mixing `Expect` (used for the record phase in record-replay-verify) with `AssertWasCalled` (used in the assert phase in arrange-act-assert). You should not mix both approaches in the same test.

Comment: That's a new mode of mocking using Rhino Mocks 3.5. Mocks/stubs returned from MockRepository.GenerateMock() and MockRepository.GenerateStub() are returned in replay mode, and do not require explicit move to replay mode. Have a look here http://www.ayende.com/Wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx#MockingwithandwithoutaninstanceofMockRepository

Comment: I think wcoenen is right, you should either use `Expect` then call `VerifyAllExpectations` or you should just `AssertWasCalled`.  Nowhere in the link that you provided does it `Expect` without also `VerifyAllExpectations` or `Expect` and `AssertWasCalled` on the same thing.

Comment: In that same help you can find a description for Expect() extension method where it is said that "The Expect() extension method creates a new expectation for this mock which must be verified/asserted later (using either the VerifyAllExpectations() or AssertWasCalled() methods)." So it does not matter actually which one you choose (here: http://www.ayende.com/Wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx#ExpectExtensionMethod)

Comment: At the same time I agree that expectation seems to be redundant as not providing any additional value to the test in the light of assertion

Answer (score 3):

Your approach will only work if your method AddLink is virtual, otherwise the .Net runtime will always run the real implementation (and rightly so).

Usually the best practise is to use interfaces when doing dependency injection (so your class expects IMyClass instead of MyClass). This way it is much easier to use mocking frameworks - not only you don't have to remember to make all methods virtual, but you avoid the issues with passing correct arguments to MyClass's constructor (which in real world is a pain)